# kinetics question

Tags: biochemistry, homework, enzyme-kinetics

An enzyme has a $V_{max}$ of 50 $\mu$mol product formed $(min * \text{mg protein})^{-1}$  and a $K_m$ of 10 $\mu$M for the substrate. When a reaction mixture contains the enzyme and a 5$\mu$M substrate, which of the following percentages of $V_{max}$ will be closest to the initial reaction rate ($V_o$)

a) 5%
b) 15%
c) 33%
d) 50%
e) 66%

Can someone explain this to me; I know michaelis-menton but I don't understand the solution to this or how to find it.

Comment: You literally just have to plug in the numbers in the Michaelis Menten equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you understand MM kinetics.

In your case the $V_{max}$ value depends on the amount of the protein. If we assume *1mg* protein, then $V_{max} = 50\frac{\mu{M}}{min}$.

According to MM kinetics:

$V = V_{max}.\frac{S}{K_M+S}$

so

$V_0 = V_{max}.\frac{S_0}{K_M+S_0} = V_{max}.\frac{5\mu{M}}{10\mu{M}+5\mu{M}} = V_{max}.\frac{1}{3}$

or in other terms

$\frac{V_0}{V_{max}} = \frac{1}{3} = 33.3\%$

Comment: @ChrisCook If you consider that inf3rno answered your question, then you should check it to indicate future users that you received an answer that helped you. It also reward the one who answered with 15 points of reputation and therefore encourage users to answer your future posts.

Comment: sorry, new to the site; I checked the check under his answer, I assume this is what you meant?  thanks